# which is the best option to handle views depending on the user?

Tags: web, view

I have two types of users that have almost the same view, the difference is that one of that views have a button to edit the information.
Which is the best practice to manage the views?
Should I create a different page for each view and redirect to the corresponding page or should I use the same page for all the profiles and handle it in the server?

Comment: I would have one view and conditionally add the button to the view if required. If the button is not in the DOM then it can't be clicked.

Comment: Yeah, I'm doing it in that way. I just want to know if it's the best option.

Comment: Doing it this way, you only have one page to maintain. The problem with having two pages is that any changes have to be done twice. When multiple people work on a code base, there is the serious risk that they will amend one page and be unaware that there is a second page to amend.